# Logic gate diagram and $K$-map.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$F(x,y,z) = \bar y \overline{(\bar x z)} + yx + y \bar z$

I needed to draw a logic gate diagram, which I already did. But my instructor also told me that if I want I can use the $K$-map to simplify it. I am not understanding $K$-map well. Can anyone please help me out, how do I do that?

Comment: Your statement simplifies to $x+\bar z$

Answer (score 0):

Mann's comment is correct.

The [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) of your function:

```
             xy
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
z     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

$F(x, y, z) = x \lor \bar{z}$